# Changing and adding arguments of method before invocation

Tags: groovy, metaprogramming

I want to reproduce the behavior of the default arguments by intercepting the call to some methods. The following code tries to give a default argument when the method *display* is called without arguments:

```
class Thing
{
    void display(String text)
    {
        println(text)
    }

    def invokeMethod(String name, args)
    {
        if(name == "display" && args.length == 0)
        {
            metaClass.getMetaMethod(name, ["some text"]).
                invoke(this, "some text")
        }
        else
        {
            metaClass.getMetaMethod(name, args).
                invoke(this, args)
        }
    }
}
Thing thing = new Thing()
thing.display("stuff") //prints "stuff"
thing.display() //nothing happens
```

However, this does not work; nothing is printed when no argument is given.

This example is not very useful but I would want to make it work; my next goal is indeed to create methods whose arguments could be given in their name. Example:

```
Add1And2()// should return 3
Add4And9()// should return 13
```

Intercepting the call to these nonexistent methods and calling an existing method that would do the addition using the numbers used in the name of the nonexistent methods would make it possible...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Class `Thing` should implement [`GroovyInterceptable`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/lang/GroovyInterceptable.html) as below to make `invokeMethod` work:

```
class Thing implements GroovyInterceptable {
    void display(String text) {
        println(text)
    }

    def invokeMethod(String name, args) {
        if(name == "display" && args.length == 0) {
            metaClass.getMetaMethod(name).invoke(this, "some text")
        } else {
            metaClass.getMetaMethod(name, args).invoke(this, args)
        }
    }
}

Thing thing = new Thing()
thing.display("stuff") //prints "stuff"
thing.display()
```